# Plotly "toImage": send the image to server instead of triggering a browser file download

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'd like the top bar *"Download plot as a png"* button to send the image data to server (for example via Javascript `fetch`) instead of triggering a browser file download.

I see there are [`Plotly.toImage`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlytoimage) and [`Plotly.downloadImage`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlydownloadimage) that could be used, but how to redefine the standard "Download plot as a png" button to do that?

```js
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [10, 15, 13, 17], mode: 'markers'}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution: how to redefine the standard "Download plot as a png" button to do that?

Please check out this code snippet. The image save button has been removed and a custom send image button has added. The button will get image as base64. it is up to you how to send the image.

Following parts of official plotly.js docs are used as reference:

- add buttons to modebar: https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/#add-buttons-to-modebar
- remove modebar buttons: https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/#remove-modebar-buttons
- static image export: https://plotly.com/javascript/static-image-export/

```js
const layout = {}
const btnCapture = {
  name: 'send image',
  icon: Plotly.Icons.camera,
  direction: 'up',
  click: async(gd) => {
    const imgBase64 = await Plotly.toImage(gd, {
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    })
    console.log('do something with image', imgBase64)
    console.log(Plotly.Icons)
  }
}
const config = {
  modeBarButtonsToAdd: [btnCapture],
  modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['toImage']
}


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  mode: 'markers',
}], layout, config)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to hide the plot's sliders before exporting as a PNG image with `Plotly.toImage`?

Comment: did you check the base64? the image only has dots and axis in it. do you mean anything else with the term `slider`? it can be checked from console.log or https://jaredwinick.github.io/base64-image-viewer/ base64 image viewers